# how to insert value of an textarea to another textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript

Well this is what i mean. Lets say i have 2 textarea:

```
<textarea id="first" class="txtarea" name="in_first" cols="80" rows="15">First Textarea</textarea>
```

and:

```
<textarea id="second" class="txtarea" name="in_second" cols="80" rows="15">First Textarea</textarea>
```

In the final result, I want to move the value of the first textarea to the second textarea with javascript only, please do not sugest me any other programing language.

I already get the value of the first textarea with code like the following:

```
var textAreaValue = $("#first").text();
```

now, how can i insert it to the second textarea? or maybe you have another method, please let me know.

Comment: Uhm, but you're using jQuery ?

Comment: We nay guess that under `any other programming language` you mean something like VBScript. If you mean jQuery, then jQuery is a JavaScript library. So what exactly do you mean by `any other programming language`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using jquery val() method:

```
$firsttextarea=$("#first").val();
$('#second').val($firsttextarea);
```

Using jquery text() method:

```
$firsttextarea=$("#first").text();
$('#second').text($firsttextarea);
```

Answer (score 2):

Then, with JS only (no libraries):

```
var firstTextArea = document.getElementById('first');
document.getElementById('second').value = first.value;

//clearing the first
first.value = '';
```

Comment: If you want to **move** the value, then you have to clear it in the source.

Comment: @JohnDoe It's quite vague as the question doesn't mention clearing anything. But then again, it's *move* :)

Comment: Just trying to be attentive :)

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript it should look like:

```
var value = document.getElementById("first").value;
document.getElementById("second").value = value;
```

Pay attention that for form elements (like `<textarea>`) you should address `value` property.

If you want to clear the value of the first `<textarea>` then do:

```
document.getElementById("first").value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery:

```
var textAreaValue = $("#first").text();
$("#second").text(textAreaValue);
```

to clear textArea you could use:

```
$("#first").text("");
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

```
$('.second').val($('.first').val());
```

This is just for your information.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<textarea id="first" class="txtarea" name="in_first" cols="80" rows="15">First Textarea</textarea>

<textarea id="second" class="txtarea" name="in_second" cols="80" rows="15">First Textarea</textarea>
```

jquery

```
var FristTextAreaValue = $("#first").val();
var SecondTextAreaValue = $("#second").val();
```